# Unable to load shared object rlang while using library(dplyr)

Tags: r, dll, dplyr, rlang

I used `install.packages("dplyr", dependencies=T)`
However when i call `library(dplyr)` it throws the following error message.

```
Loading required package: dplyr
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Client/R_SERVER/library/rlang/libs/x64/rlang.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I first tried downloading rlang package but it gave me an error which says:
`Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rlang’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)`

I then copied the rlang package from a different path to the path where my R library exists and it throws an error of "Enrty point not found"

Could someone help me with a solution?

Comment: Try this `install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang", build_vignettes = TRUE)`

Comment: Which OS are you running on?

Comment: Okay that solution helps. Thanks @BappaDas

Comment: @z-cool this is on windows 10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang", build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

before installing the `dplyr` package.