# Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding

Tags: r, rtools

I need to install the “lifecycle” package in order to run an R code but I’m getting the error below.

I’ve already uninstalled and re-installed both RTools and R for Windows with no luck.

The WARNING message states to install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding – how do I find out what the ‘appropriate’ version that I would need to install?

```
>install.packages("lifecycle")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘c:/RLibrary’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘cli’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions
  are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        2.5.0  3.4.1              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.0  1.0.3             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/cli_2.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 534931 bytes (522 KB)
downloaded 522 KB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpM95qM9\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘lifecycle’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
downloaded 104 KB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'c:/RLibrary/rlang/libs/x64/rlang.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load -> inDL
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'c:/RLibrary/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58771989/unable-to-load-shared-object-rlang-while-using-librarydplyr#58773294 (in your case: before installing or re-installing {lifecycle}) ?

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with `rlang` somehow. Can you see if you can run `install.packages("rlang")` and `library(rlang)` with out an error first?

Comment: Re "how do I find out what the ‘appropriate’ version that I would need to install?":  It depends on your version of R.  See this page:  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ .

Comment: `R.version` to get your R version

Comment: @MrFlick - I have the rlang package installed, but, here's the error I'm getting when running library(rlang) `> packageVersion("rlang")
[1] ‘1.0.6’
> library(rlang)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rlang’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'c:/RLibrary/rlang/libs/x64/rlang.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rlang’ was built under R version 4.3.0`

Comment: The message says "Warning message: package ‘rlang’ was built under R version 4.3.0"? That is odd because 4.3.0 isn't even released yet. How did you install that package?

Comment: @MrFlick I manually added it from a zipped binary file here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/index.html since the error message I'm getting when attempting to install "lifecycle" package is requiring "rlang" version 1.0.6

Comment: You mean you downloaded the Windows zipped binary for `r-devel`? If you are not running a development version of R, then you should not use that download. You should use the ` r-release` verison if you need to use the zip, otherwise you should just be installing from CRAN via `install.packages("rlang"). But now you'll have to manually uninstall that bad version with `remove.packages()`. If `library(rlang)` doesn't run without error, then R considered the package missing.

Comment: @MrFlick - I uninstalled using remove.packages("rlang") and re-installed using install.packages("rlang") and I'm receiving a new error `> library("rlang")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rlang’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 lazy-load database 'c:/RLibrary/rlang/R/rlang.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1`

Comment: That sounds like the file was corrupted when it was downloaded from CRAN. What version of R are you using (`R.version.string`)? What CRAN mirror are you using (`options("repos")`)?  Are you behind a firewall that may be blocking/intercepting network requests? Have you been able to install any other packages? I would try removing and installing again. Make sure the c:/RLibrary/rlang/R/rlang.rdb is gone after you remove the package.

Comment: @MrFlick - `> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)"
> options("repos")
$repos
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @MrFlick - how would I be able to check for firewalls that my be blocking network requests? And confirming that c:/RLibrary/rlang/R/rlang.rdb is removed after remove.packages()